# Obout Grid in UpdatePanel gets disabled on asynchronous postbacks

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, obout

I have a Obout Grid inside usercontrol and usercontrol is inside updatepanel. User control is not loaded dynamically. It is registered and a static reference is made. Obout Grid is getting disabled , whenever there is an asynchronous postback from grid or usercontrol.

I cannot select any rown or do anything on the grid. I can see that Obout grid is getting updated or usercontrol is working good, as same usercontrol is referred in many other places.

Help is really appreciated. I really cannot understand why the Obout grid is getting disabled. Initial load is good and also when grid makes a full postback it works good,but not for asynchronous postback ( I think so).

**Edit**:

`Enabled` is `true`. Grid is also not readonly. But i cannot click on grid or any buttons on my grid.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplSelectOwner" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate> 
      <tuc:selectOwner ID="uclSelectOwner" runat="server"/> </ContentTemplate> 
   <ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What does disabled mean apat from what you've mentioned. Is `Enabled` property `false`? It would also be helpful if you would show us some code, maybe a reproducable, simplified version. At least the UpdatePanel.

Comment: You can delete your comment. I've edited your question(simply click on the `edit`-link below the question). in the edit-view click the question-mark to get help by formatting etc(f.e. click the `code` tag next to see how you can fomat the code).

Comment: Thank you, any hellp is really  appreciated. I am kind of struck,donot know what is happening.

Comment: Have you tied to set UpdateMode to "Always". Normally you would need to call `Update` on the UpdatePanel in the codebehind when you set it to "Conditional".

Comment: I tried to set UpdateMode to "Always", then my page is going into infinte Loop. I even tried explictly calling updatepanel.update() when postbacks happen in usercontrol. Still it didnot work.

Comment: I need help on this, I tried adding my usercontrol dynamically to page, still same problem. For some reason for certain actions grid works good like sorting or  selecting a record, I notice that when sorting or selecting a record scriptmanager.IsAsynchPostBack is false and grid works good even after sorting and selecting. If there is any other action, usercontrol does a asynchronous postback  scriptmanager.IsAsynchPostBack is true and Grid stops working liek disabled. help is really appreciated.

Comment: can anybody here help me on this. I have a update panel user control and inside usercontrol obout grid. When I keep grid directly under updatepanel works great even when i call usercontorl in a pge it works greata,but when i combine updatepanel and then in side update panel user control and inside user control obout grid, gird gets disabled after a asynchronous postback from usercontrol.

Comment: I'm afraid that too few people have experiences with Obout Grid(just as me).

Comment: I'm having the same problem. 

Upon initial page load, the obout grid renders/loads up as expected. But as soon as the UpdatePanel get a partial postback and the grid reloads it starts to have problems. It looks like not all the client side scripts fire off and the grid fails to initialize. I have been contacting the obout support team, but have not receive an solution to work around or fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in `pageinit` assign:

```
this.grid.id= this.id +"grid";
```

The grid id repeat for each user control, then only one funk.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set CallbackMode property of grid to false ([link](http://www.obout.com/grid/aspnet_ajax_postbackmode.aspx)).